# How to remove parent tag while keeping its child element

Tags: xml, xslt

How to remove the parent tag while keeping its children, if child and parent tag order is not as expected?

`xml` input is:

```
<div>
<b>
<a>correct info</a>
</b>
</div>
<div>
<b>
<a>additional info</a>
<i>italic form</i>
</b>.

<xsl:template match="b/a">
       <xsl:copy-of select="a"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Actual result is:

```
<div> 
<b/>
</div>
<div>
</b>
<i>italic form</i>
</div>
```

Expected result:

```
    <div>
    <a>correct info</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a>additional info</a>
    <i>italic form</i>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `order not as expected` ? What should be the condition to remove parent tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="b/a">
   <xsl:copy-of select="a"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="b">
   <xsl:copy-of select="a"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This solution is woorking for the above condition only.
If my code is like this: <div>
<b>
<a>correct info</a>
</b>
</div>
<div>
<b>
<a>additional info</a>
<i>italic form</i>
</b><a><b>exact info</b></div> then it will not work. Please suggest the solution if I need to remove <b> tag if <a> comes under <b> tag only.

Comment: Actual output:   <div>
    <a>correct info</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a>additional info</a>
    <i>italic form</i> <a>exact info</a>
</div>
Expected output:  <div>
    <a>correct info</a>
    </div>
    <div>
    <a>additional info</a>
    <i>italic form</i><a><b>exact info</a></b>
</div>

Comment: @RichaBajaj Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and explain the additional requirements there. I **think** you want to restrict the above to `<xsl:template match="b[a]">` but I cannot read your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific element 'a' as a child element to 'b' michael.hor's solution works.
id you can have any element as children. 
here in example you have a and i as  b's children then

```
<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="suppress"/>       
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()[not(self::b)]" mode="suppress">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="suppress"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```